# HTML format data inside webview Binded to a listview

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, webview, windows-store-apps

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/09/26/binding-html-to-a-webview-with-attached-properties.aspx
I am following this post to bind my HTML data to my webview But adding it to my listview I am facing the problem of data being populated for Listview Itemselected event.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource HtmlSource}}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Name="DatabaseStack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                <WebView  local:MyExtensions.HTML="{Binding Source={StaticResource HtmlSource}, Path=HTML}" Height="200" Width="1000" />


        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now inside the C# code

```
HtmlSource.Source = HTMLStrings;
```

During execution i am getting the values for first item data in every ListView member and when I select the second item it gets populated throughout my ListView when the extended method gets called

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HTMLProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HTML", typeof(string), typeof(MyExtensions), new PropertyMetadata("",new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHTMLChanged)));

private static void OnHTMLChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{

    WebView wv = d as WebView; 
    if (wv != null) 
    { 
        wv.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue); 
    } 
}
```

How can I populate my listview without having to depend on Dependency Property to display my data in webview or if there's one that I can use please help. I want to populate my Listview with each Item being displayed in its respective template instead of having to depend on my selected item event to display each data repetitively in every itemtemplate

Comment: @Raphael Meidi Please provide me the answer also.

Answer (score 2):

I may be crazy, but shouldn't it be more like

```
<WebView  local:MyExtensions.HTML="{Binding Path=HTML}" Height="200" Width="1000" />
```

So you're using the current bound values of the ItemTemplate instead of possibly resetting it per execution?

http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-listvew-to-display-complex-data.html

Comment: yes thats exactly right. I too solved it just two days ago and since I had already started the bounty wanted someone else to enjoy the points. Enjoy your points. Hope @user3541379 is happy now.